Is the term "people of the book" used as a slur?
What exactly is the tone with what this term is used? Is it used respectfully or is it an racial epitah. What exactly is the context behind this phrase?

It is not used as a slur.
It means people who were given the scripture (Torah and Gospel) by Allah or who claim to follow the teachings from these revealed books, and that is the context behind it. In Islam it is a technical term and is the name of a genus of people which is composed of those who are or were what you would call Jews and Christians, and (with some disagreements) also some other religions.
The term by itself doesn't imply respect nor disdain for those being referred by it. It can be used when praising such as when used for those among them who converted to Islam:

وإن من أهل الكتاب لمن يؤمن بالله وما أنزل إليكم وما أنزل إليهم خاشعين لله لا يشترون بآيات الله ثمنا قليلا أولئك لهم أجرهم عند ربهم إن الله سريع الحساب
And indeed, among the People of the Scripture are those who believe in Allah and what was revealed to you and what was revealed to them, [being] humbly submissive to Allah. They do not exchange the verses of Allah for a small price. Those will have their reward with their Lord. Indeed, Allah is swift in account.
— Quran 3:199


ثلاثة لهم أجران رجل من أهل الكتاب آمن بنبيه، وآمن بمحمد صلى الله عليه وسلم
Three persons will have a double reward: A person from the People of the Scripture who believed in his prophet and then believed in Muhammad ﷺ ...
— Bukhari

It can also be used when reproaching those of them who disbelieve and do evil deeds, such as:

إن الذين كفروا من أهل الكتاب والمشركين في نار جهنم خالدين فيها أولئك هم شر البرية
Indeed, they who disbelieved among the People of the Scripture and the polytheists will be in the fire of Hell, abiding eternally therein. Those are the worst of creatures.
— Quran 98:6

